# Why did I get this hat today?

Tags: support, hats

Today I was given the `O Tannenbaum` hat, but the description says `ask, answer, or vote on December 25th`, I thought we were using UTC time here?

If so why did I get this today?

It is only the 24th of December UTC, I added the hat (tree?) to my profile picture, so you can see it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Why are date-based hats awarded too early?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/why-are-date-based-hats-awarded-too-early) ?

Comment: @hg8 Good find, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From : [Why are date-based hats awarded too early?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/why-are-date-based-hats-awarded-too-early)

> So, the official answer is: we over-awarded the hat so that people in
>   Auckland / Tokyo / Shanghai / Vanuatu wouldn't have to wait until
>   their midday to receive it.
>
> You're all mostly programmers, so you should be reasonably familiar
>   with how much of a headache timezones can be sometimes. Since Stack
>   Exchange is run on UTC, we have to leave a +/- 12 hour buffer so that
>   the nations around the International Date Line have just as much
>   opportunity to grab hats as people along the 0 longitude.
>
> This behavior will also occur for the other hats that are
>   date-sensitive. This included L'Chaim, and will include Tis the Season
>   and the New Year's Eve Hat / Auld Lang Syne.
>
> **Basically: Don't panic! It's a feature, not a bug!**

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/302251) on [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer):

> Unless the requirement mentions a specific timezone, hats that are date-based are often awarded for 14 hours before and 12 hours after the specified date in UTC, to accomodate people everywhere in the world. This means you can earn such a hat even though for you it's not even that day yet.

Doing the math:

```
25 Dec 2015 00:00 AM UTC - 14h = 24 Dec 2015 10:00 AM UTC
25 Dec 2015 00:00 AM UTC + 12h = 25 Dec 2015 12:00 AM UTC
```

This means that the hat is actually awarded in the timeframe ranging from 24 Dec 2015 10:00 AM UTC to 25 Dec 2015 12:00 AM UTC.

This explains why it's currently 11.15 UTC and you've been awarded the hat already.